# Will this 24 V relay driver work?

Tags: power, relay, opto-isolator, esp32, 24v

I am not sure about the 24 V which drives the transistor base. Is this circuit correct? Do I need some modifications?

The current rating for D2 is 200 mA.  Is that high enough?

[image]

Comment: The optocoupler is useless bloat. Just pick a BJT or MOSFET that you can drive directly from the 3.3V signal.

Comment: @Lundin:  The circuit shows two grounds.  Isolation may actually be needed for this particular task.

Comment: 1.  Do you really need isolation?  2. How much current will the relay coil draw on 24V?  That will determine the required current rating for D2 and Q1.

Comment: 4148 seems for signal switching; I think you need a Schottky for flyback.

Comment: This circuit uses more base current driving the transistor base than collector current needed driving the relay. If R2 is a 100mW resistor it will burn up.

Comment: Relay coil Current is 16.7mA @24 VDC, I consider approx. 10 times the of the for the rated current of 200ma and also for 1 Sec it can handle 1A peak current.  hear is the datasheet  https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/308/1/LL4148_D-1810583.pdf

Comment: The value of R2 is the main concern, can anyone please explain it in more detail?

Do I need to increase the value of R2 to match Collector Current for LTV-817S which is 50mA.

Comment: Regarding the diode, check out [What should be considered when picking a flyback diode?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/280393) Iirc we concluded that a plain old 1N4148 would work just fine. I'd use a 1N400x though because they are about as cheap but more rugged.

Comment: "Do I need to increase [?] the value of R2 to match Collector Current for LTV-817S which is 50mA."  I'm assuming you meant decrease, but no, you should **not** match the 50 mA current.  50 mA is the absolute *maximum* collector current.  The 1k resistor will keep it well below the limit.

Comment: @JRE Naturally it shows two grounds since there's a primary and secondary. But there is no obvious reason for it. The Arduino crowd is known to splatter optocouplers left and right, just because some of the hobby relay boards for Arduino comes with fool proof isolation and that one is used as reference design. I'm willing to bet this is also the case here, since it says ESP32. People ought to realize that a relay already provides galvanic isolation.

Comment: Actually, I am using an isolated DC-DC converter power supply of 24 -5V, so the 24V system is completely isolated from 5V/3.3V ground.  
Isolating 230V (relay voltage is not an objective here.